# Jersey route to @Consumes based on MediaType parameter?

Tags: java, jersey

I suspect this can't be done, but maybe there's a trick I'm missing. I want to use to different methods that take the same MediaType, but have different parameters to the mediatype. Perhaps this is abusing MediaType parameters...

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json;internal=true")
public Response handleInternal(String request) {
}
@POST
@Consumes("application/json;internal=false")
public Response handleExternal(String request) {
}
```

Jersey complains I have two methods consuming the same MediaType, which is true. I was hoping it'd go on to pick the right one by the parameter. Is there some trick to making this work? In a nutshell, I have two use cases for how to treat the information coming in (specifically, domain level validation) and this seemed like a decent way to distinguish between those two.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **MessageBodyReader** along with two user types, one for internal json and the other for external json

1- Create two types than extends String (via delegation -using lombok is easier-):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InternalJSON {
    @Delegate
    private final String _theJSONStr;
}
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExternalJSON {
    @Delegate
    private final String _theJSONStr;
}
```

2- Create the MessageBodyReader type

```
@Provider
public class MyRequestTypeMapper 
      implements MessageBodyReader<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(final Class<?> type,final Type genericType,
                                  final Annotation[] annotations,
                                  final MediaType mediaType) {
            // this matches both application/json;internal=true and application/json;internal=false
            return mediaType.isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE); 
    }
        @Override
        public Object readFrom(final Class<Object> type,final Type genericType,
                               final Annotation[] annotations,
                               final MediaType mediaType,
                               final MultivaluedMap<String,String> httpHeaders,
                               final InputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
                                                                       WebApplicationException {
            if (mediaType.getSubType().equals("internal=true") {
                // Build an InternalJSON instance parsing entityStream
                // ... perhaps using JACKSON or JAXB by hand
            } else if (mediaType.getSubType().equals("internal=false") {
                // Build an ExternalJSON instance parsing entityStream
                // ... perhaps using JACKSON or JAXB by hand
            }
        }
}
```

3- Register your MessageBodyReader at the Application (this is optional since jersey will scan the classpath for @Provider annotated types

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    ... 
    s.add(MyRequestTypeMapper .class);

    return s;
}
```

4- Reformat your rest methods usgin the two user types for internal and external json

Comment: Thanks for the detail, but the cure seems worse than the problem :). My backup plan is to just look at the Content-Type header and if/else to my two different methods based on the "internal" parameter value.